# Using Hawkular for Rest services built using CXF

Tags: trace, zipkin, hawkular, opentracing

I am new to Distributed Tracing / Hawkular. And would like to experiment tracing for my distributed cxf rest services using hawkular.
Will it be possible to trace cxf servcies using hawkular and if any one has doc or reference sample app, that will be great.

Also, is there any other tracing tool which can solve this requirement(tracing java cxf rest services). Zipkin-brave has a feature for this which I am looking at also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend instrumenting your application using the OpenTracing API, and later choose a concrete implementation. Under the Hawkular project, there's the Hawkular APM module which provides a solution for capturing, visualizing and making sense of the data. However, we (Hawkular APM) recently decided to join the Jaeger project, to have a better support for the OpenTracing case. We expect to have similar features from Hawkular APM ported to Jaeger "soon".

For OpenTracing, there are quite a few "framework integrations" under the [OpenTracing Contrib organization](https://github.com/opentracing-contrib), including JAX-RS, which might serve as base or reference for a CXF-specific implementation. If nothing suits you, I'm certain we'd welcome a contribution.

If you are just looking to learn OpenTracing, I'd suggest taking a look at the Hawkular APM's example directory, including a [`vertx-opentracing` example](https://github.com/hawkular/hawkular-apm/tree/master/examples/vertx-opentracing).

Comment: thnx will try that.